# Save and restore last window size in C++

Tags: winapi

How to save and restore last window size in Win32 API C/C++ without writing anything to system registry.

Comment: Write the information to a file rather than the registry.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, the best you can do is [GetWindowPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633518%28VS.85%29.aspx), which will get you the restore coordinates through `WINDOWPLACEMENT.rcNormalPosition`.

Comment: Will GetWindowPlacement work even after the program is restarted?

Comment: Not sure actually. Why don't you try and see?